# Wait For View to be Drawn - Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am working with Espresso to write some test for my android app.

I am able to use onView() to get references to views then check them and run actions.

My problem occurs when I retrieve data from a background task. espresso waits until the task is completed then I take a screenshot. Unfortunately the activity hasn't yet drawn the views with the data onto the screen. so I get a screen shot of a split second before the actualy screen I want.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Could you provide some of your code?

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the situation, one of these should work.

Before you take you screenshot you can assert check that a view is showing:

```
onView(withId(R.id.id_of_view_to_be_screenshoted)).check(ViewAssertions.matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Also, you could do this ( based on idea from @ValeraZakharov ) :

```
    onView(withId(R.id.id_of_view_to_be_screenshoted)).perform(new ViewAction() {
         ......
        public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle();
        }
    });
```